# What is standard about standard cells in layout designing?

Tags: layout, vlsi, standard, physical-design, chip-design

Why are standard cells called 'standard' cells? Why couldn't it be just cells? What is Standard about them? (I'm talking about the common terminology used in layout designing wherein the standard cells are the building blocks of a bigger circuit.)

Comment: Cells can mean many things... you need to add a reference to the question.

Comment: As pertaining to what? FPGA's? Be specific

Answer (score 5):

Standard cells usually refer to blocks of logic that are arranged into a library of elements. This is the library you buy from a fabrication facility (FAB) when you order their cervices for chip fabrication. These "cells" are coming fully validated and characterized by the vendor for each particular fabrication node, with all timing and power consumption etc.

These cells are called "standard" as opposite to full-custom design of logic blocks from basic layout primitives. Some people used to do this in the past to take potential speed advantage of various odd techniques such as self-clocking (domino) logic, or if some special analog functions are needed. In these "non-standard" cases the chip design house takes responsibility to validate (qualify) their design, as opposite to take standard well characterized cells from FAB vendor.

Answer (score 0):

Typically the standard cells have a uniform HEIGHT, with the other 2_D dimension being variable, based on how many transistors and other components are in the circuit for a particular cell.

Also the power and GND points will be well-defined and perhaps protruding and available to automatically contact the top-layer VDD/GND routes simply by dropping the cell into the layout.

The signal IN/OUT nodes will be clearly labeled and ready to wire up in the routing channels; that is, brought out at designated metal layers for routing.

Automatic place-and-route tools take big advantage of standard cells.